# CMAKE - getting a path using get_filename_component

Tags: cmake

I have a path and i would like to get the path starting from a specific path
This is my current path

```
   macro(MY_MACRO base)

    foreach(ITEM ${ARGN})
       get_filename_component(ITEM_PATH ${ITEM} DIRECTORY)
       get_filename_component(ITEM_EXT ${ITEM} EXT)
       source_group("${ITEM_PATH}" FILES ${ITEM})
       MESSAGE ("${ITEM_PATH}")
    endforeach()

    endmacro()
```

The above outputs this

```
/Users/admin/main/project/module/pilot/pilot/src/proA
/Users/admin/main/project/module/pilot/guide/src/proB
```

I would like it to just display the path starting from the last level
it should only show the path after the folder pilot
so it should show something like this

```
pilot/src/proA
guide/src/proB
```

Not the full path

Comment: Just curious, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command [file(RELATIVE_PATH)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/file.html) computes relative path. Usage is straightforward:

```
file(RELATIVE_PATH
    ITEM_PATH_REL # Output variable
    "/Users/admin/main/project/module/pilot" # Base directory
    ${ITEM_PATH} # Absolute path to the file
)
message("Relative path: ${ITEM_PATH_REL}")
```

Comment: When i try this it says file RELATIVE_PATH must be passed a full path to the file:

Comment: Yes, the last argument should be full path. Exactly this is written in the comments to the example.